# Get specific text value of parent without child

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to use Xpath to get the text of the parent `anchor` without also getting the text from the `span` of the example below:

```
<a id="readingListBtn" class="btn btn-transparent" title="Reading List" href="javascript:void(0);">
<span class="icon icon_headerBookmark">Header Bookmark</span>
0
</a>
```

The Xpath I'm using (`//a[@id = 'readingListBtn']`) returns `"Header Bookmark0"`, but I'm just interested in the `"0"` part.

Answer (score 3):

Just get the direct text child:

```
//a[@id = 'readingListBtn']/text()
```

Comment: like i stated above, that returns the combined `Header Bookmark` and `0`. i just want the `0`.

Comment: @jossetter This answer is correct; what you state cannot be happening. Note that there are two child text nodes in your sample: `\n` and `\n0\n`.